# Is it possible to limit number of emails per user per period on Exim?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, exim

I'm wondering if it's possible to limit number of emails allowed from a specific email account on Exim (maybe set a 20 email per hour limit for ab@test.com).

I'd like to see if I can use this as a way to control spam.

I appreciate any direction on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can limit incoming messages.  (Search for "Rate Limiting" in the specification?)  However, my experience is that this won't help much if at all.  However, It could help prevent servers on your network from spewing spam if they get infected.

I use a number of features for [Blocking Spam with Exim](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/blocking-spam-with-exim/).  One the the most effective is to inject delays for servers which are not configured correctly.  This may cause some problems for automated email systems (airlines, banks, governments, advertisers, etc.), but has little impact on person mail.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I will checkout the Systemajik link.

Comment: Also [greylisting](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/SimpleGreylisting) can help.

Comment: @dsznajder I do use greylisting but exclude hosts that pass all validations, or other conditions which indicate that the host will eventually pass.